# How to remove animation after setting alarm using AlarmClock?

Tags: android, android-animation, alarm, setalarmclock

In my project I am using [AlarmClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock) which sets alarm at certain time. Since I didn't want to display the system's default clock post setting the alarm I used `AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI` but despite this after changing activity or quitting app following weird animation occurs.

[image]

To clear things up this animation is not animation of quitting/changing my activities. Moreover I tested this function in isolation and I am sure that these lines of code make that happen.

-------AlarmClock method-------

```
private void alarmClock(int hour, int minute) {
        Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minute);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS, Calendar.THURSDAY);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Time for taking morning medicine!");
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

In `AndroidManifest` I included following line

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

My first thought was that despite of disabling UI with `AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI` I still need to disable animation while using intent with `overridePendingTransition(0, 0)` but still it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: This might be a problem in your emulator. Just try your app in other phone and check whether this animation occurs or not

Comment: You're probably right, on my phone there isn't any animation.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a wild guess. But it may be that your EXTRA_SKIP_UI is being ignored according to the documentation:

(emphasis mine)

> This action requests an alarm to be set for a given time of day. If no
>   time of day is specified, an implementation should start an activity
>   that is capable of setting an alarm (**EXTRA_SKIP_UI is ignored in
>   this case**).
>
> If a time of day is specified, and EXTRA_SKIP_UI is true, **and the
>   alarm is not repeating**, the implementation should remove this alarm
>   after it has been dismissed.

Can you double check that you're not falling into these cases?

Comment: Surprisingly aforementioned animation doesn't occur on my phone so it may be emulator fault.